# Characters messed up in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-ide

My android studio looks like you can see in the picture below and I don't know why.

I have  already tried to re-install it, but my problem is still not fixed. I tried to change the IDE Encoding, but this is not working either.

What is wrong with android studio and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :D, my problem is on my IDE, is picture of the issus, if you click on "My Issus :S" you may see the picture of my IDE problem

Comment: try to put in another language